# WCF. REST architecture + basic authentication. .NET 4

Tags: wcf, json, authentication, rest, basic-authentication

I need an advice from people who already used base authentication in WCF Service.

I found a lot of examples how to do it like:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/BasicAuthWCFRest.aspx

and **WcfRestContrib**. But first example for .NET 3.5 and second is not supported by anymore by author. Maybe in .NET 4 things a better and we have some functionality that can help me with this issue? Will appreciate any clues and information.

And for some reason i even cannot get data from secured server because of  strange parse error when trying to get data with JQuery. Without basic authentication everything working fine and with json cannot be parsed. Maybe somebody meet such problem.

Comment: It's better if you can paste your error information here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a problem with the OPTIONS call which is issued when using basic authentication in jquery. You can solve this by adding an global.asax to your project and add the following code:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EnableCrossDomainAjaxCall();
}

private void EnableCrossDomainAjaxCall()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, Accept");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

You can also download an example solution here: http://sameproblemmorecode.blogspot.com/2011/10/creating-secure-restfull-wcf-service.html

Comment: Many thanks for the link - very helpful.  A small and concise example on how to do this.